# Japanese manga in which the main character can purchase stuff from Earth and meets a forest cat, a merchant daughter, and a feline adventurer

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

1. The main character (MC) can purchase stuff from Earth.
2. The MC meets a forest cat chapters in the manga, and the cat follows him to a house the MC built in the forest.
3. The MC meets a merchant daughter after selling stuff from Earth, but said daughter got abducted by bandits and he provides weapons and armor to adventurers to get her back from the bandits.
4. The MC brings construction equipment/machinery from Earth, but the residents of the world thinks it's just summoning magic that brings monsters.
5. In said house, the MC built all by himself, using a blueprint obtained from the cross-isekai shop. A feline adventurer and as mentioned for the forest cat above, moves inside with him.
6. He had some trouble with some nobles, disappeared suddenly along with the house without telling the merchant daughter. She kinda stalks him and reunited with him in another town.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is ***[The Daily Life of a Middle-Aged Online Shopper in Another World](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/the-daily-life-of-a-middle-aged-online-shopper-in-another-world)***.

> Ken'ichi, a single man in his 40s, is suddenly transferred to another world. As he navigates his way through the dangerous forests of that world, he realizes that he can use a huge online shopping site. Ken'ichi aims to use his cheat ability to live a slow life in another world!

Kenichi Hamada, a 38-year-old freelance manga artist, is transported to a forest in another world and discovers that he can bring up video game-like status screens that allow him to sell things and use the money to buy products from Earth. He also has an 'item box' (like a pocket dimension) he can store things in.

In chapter 1, he travels to a city called Dahlia and sets up a market stall there.

In chapter 2, he meets a cat girl named Myarei and, through her, makes friends with other members of her tribe of cat people.

In chapter 3, he meets a young woman named Primula, and subsequently her father, Mallow, the owner of a trading company, with whom he forms a business arrangement.

In chapter 4, he builds a house in the forest, using an excavator from Earth to clear land for it.

> [image: "The Daily Life of a Middle-Aged Online Shopper in Another World," chapter 4, page 25.]

In chapter 5, he finds a wounded forest cat in the woods and takes it home to treat its injuries.

In chapter 7, he learns from Mallow that Primula has been kidnapped by a group of bandits.

In chapters 8-9, he rescues Primula from the bandits with the help of Myarei and other people equipped with weapons and armour he supplied them with. He attacks the bandits with the excavator, which they think is a monster.

> [image: "The Daily Life of a Middle-Aged Online Shopper in Another World," chapter 8, page 21.]

In chapter 10, he meets a little girl named Anemone, who quickly becomes attached to him and moves into his house to live with him and the forest cat.

In chapter 11, he hears that nobles are looking for him and decides to leave town on a motorcycle, worried that he might be drafted as a mage and made to work for them. He takes Anemone and the forest cat with him and brings his house as well in his item box.

In chapter 16, he's confronted by Primula in another town, who was upset that he left without telling her and tracked him down to his current location.